# Вращение круга SVG с элементом группы

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, svg-animation

Я хотел бы вращать SVG-круг, не давая вращаться другим элементам

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я пытаюсь повернуть круг (белого цвета) с помощью rotateZ (15 градусов),  то это выглядит, как на рисунке ниже:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это мой прогресс до сих пор: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/41hrnojs/)

Я хотел бы достичь

Круг (белого цвета) вращается, когда происходит клик по белому кругу

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Rotating a SVG circle with group element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63131408/rotating-a-svg-circle-with-group-element) от участника  [@JackPowell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6334902/jackpowell).</sub>

```
<svg viewBox="0 0 1400 900" style="outline:1px solid red;">
    <g>
       <clipPath id="hexagonal-mask">
          <circle cx="700" cy="100" r="705" ></circle>
       </clipPath>
    </g> 
    <a>
     <image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/800/400"  style="transform: translateY(-140px);"/>
    </a>

    <g  style="transform-origin: 701px -5%; transform: rotateZ(15deg)">
        <circle cx="701" cy="0" r="665" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1px" fill="transparent"  style="transform: translateY(-50px);" ></circle>
       
        <!-- center dot -->
        <g id="f" class="fuck">
            <circle cx="701" cy="615" r="15" fill="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000">
                
            </circle> 
            <path  stroke="#000" stroke-width="1px" d="M701 630 701 690"></path>
           
            <text x="672" y="720" font-family="'Playfair Display', serif" font-size="2em" font-weight="bold" fill="#9d9e9f">2007</text>
            <text x="640" y="730" font-family="'Playfair Display', serif" font-size="2.85em" font-weight="bold" fill="#000">
                <tspan x="640" dy="40">Lorem</tspan>
                <tspan x="640" dy="45">Ipsum</tspan>
            </text>
            
            <animateMotion 
               xlink:href="#f"
               dur="1s"
               begin="click"
               fill="freeze"
               path="M0 100 Q50 80 -399 -135"
               repeatCount="1">
                
            </animateMotion>
        </g>
        
        
        

        <!-- left dot -->
        <g>
            <!-- <circle cx="305" cy="485" r="15" fill="#fff"></circle> -->
            <circle cx="302" cy="480" r="15" fill="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000"></circle>
            <path stroke="#000" stroke-width="1px" d="M302 495 305 675"></path>
        </g>

        <!-- right dot -->
        <g>
            <circle cx="1100" cy="480" r="15" fill="#fff" stroke-width="4" stroke="#000"></circle>
            <path  stroke="#000" stroke-width="1px" d="M1100 495 1100 675"></path>
        </g>
    </g>

</svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/63131408/7394871

Answer (score 4):

Вместо того, чтобы вращать все, я бы вычислял положение точек на круге и использовал координаты точек, чтобы нарисовать линию и текст.

Для этого я использую JavaScript. Наиболее важной частью в скрипте является функция, используемая для вычисления новой позиции повернутой точки: `rotatePoint (p, c, rot)`

Обратите внимание, что в SVG я устранил бесполезные преобразования.

```js
let theG = document.querySelector("#theG");
//координаты центра круга
let center = { x: 700, y: -40 };
//вращение в радианах
let rot = .6;
//функция для расчета новой позиции повернутой точки
function rotatePoint(p, c, rot) {
  // p: точка
  // c: центр вращеня
  // rot: вращение
  let cos = Math.cos(rot);
  let sin = Math.sin(rot);
  return {
    x: c.x + (p.x - c.x) * cos - (p.y - c.y) * sin,
    y: c.y + (p.x - c.x) * sin + (p.y - c.y) * cos
  };
}


//все группы с классом .dot
let groups = theG.querySelectorAll(".dot");
let points = [];

groups.forEach((g) => {
  let dot = g.querySelector("circle");
  let p = {};

  p.x = dot.getAttribute("cx");
  p.y = dot.getAttribute("cy");
  
  points.push(p)
});


itr.addEventListener("input",()=>{
  
let rot = itr.value;

groups.forEach((g,i) => {
  
  let dot = g.querySelector("circle");
  let line = g.querySelector("line");
  let t1 = g.querySelectorAll("text")[0];

  let newPoint = rotatePoint(points[i], center, rot);

  dot.setAttribute("cx", newPoint.x);
  dot.setAttribute("cy", newPoint.y);

  line.setAttribute("x1", newPoint.x);
  line.setAttribute("x2", newPoint.x);
  line.setAttribute("y1", newPoint.y);
  line.setAttribute("y2", newPoint.y + 180);

  t1.setAttribute("x", newPoint.x);
  t1.setAttribute("y", newPoint.y + 200);

});
  
});
```

```css
input{width:90vw;}
p{text-align:center;}
text{text-anchor:middle}

line{stroke:#000; stroke-width:1px; }
```

```html
<p><input type="range" id="itr" min="-.85" max=".85" value="0" step=".01" /></p>

<svg viewBox="0 0 1400 900" style="outline:1px solid red;" >
   <defs>
    <clipPath id="hexagonal-mask">
      <circle cx="700" cy="-40" r="705"></circle>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/222579/castell.jpg"></image>
  <circle cx="700" cy="-40" r="655" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1px" fill="transparent"></circle>
  <g id="theG">

    <g class="dot">
      <circle cx="700" cy="615" r="15" fill="#fff"></circle>
      <line x1="700" y1="615" x2="700" y2="795"></line>
      <text x="700" y="815" font-family="'Playfair Display', serif" font-size="2em" font-weight="bold" fill="#9d9e9f">2007</text>
    </g>

    <g class="dot">
      <circle cx="302" cy="480" r="15" fill="#fff"></circle>
      <line x1="302" y1="480" x2="302" y2="660"></line>
      <text x="302" y="680" font-family="'Playfair Display', serif" font-size="2em" font-weight="bold" fill="#9d9e9f">2006</text>
    </g>

    <g class="dot">
      <circle cx="1100" cy="480" r="15" fill="#fff"></circle>
      <line x1="1100" y1="480" x2="1100" y2="660"></line>
      <text x="1100" y="680" font-family="'Playfair Display', serif" font-size="2em" font-weight="bold" fill="#9d9e9f">2008</text>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Rotating a SVG circle with group element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63133867/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Мне было интересно,  можно ли  сделать это без JavaScript. В следующей демонстрации я использую JavaScript только для того, чтобы изменить значение поворота.
Поскольку я использую svg-преобразования, углы в градусах, а не в радианах.

Основная идея заключается в следующем: я создаю вложенный элемент SVG. Пока я поворачиваю `theG` в одном направлении, мне нужно повернуть линию и текст на одинаковое количество градусов в противоположном направлении. Проблема в том, что при вращении `theG` точки меняют положение, и мне нужно знать это положение, чтобы использовать его в качестве отправной точки для строки и текста.

Решение состоит в том, чтобы поместить всё в вложенный SVG, где всё остается в том же положении, и вращать вложенный SVG. Как видно в SVG 1.1, элемент не допускает атрибут transform. Поэтому я поместил все вложенные svg в группу и вместо этого повернул группу.

```js
itr.addEventListener("input",()=>{
 
let rot = itr.value;
theG.setAttribute("transform",`rotate(${rot} 700 -40)`) 
dot2006.setAttribute("transform",`rotate(${-rot} 302 480)`); 
dot2007.setAttribute("transform",`rotate(${-rot} 700 600)`);
dot2008.setAttribute("transform",`rotate(${-rot} 1100 480)`);  
});
```

```css
input{width:90vw;}
p{text-align:center;}
text{text-anchor:middle; font-family:'Playfair Display' serif; font-size:2em; font-weight:bold; fill:#9d9e9f;}

line{stroke:#000; stroke-width:1px; }
```

```html
<p><input type="range" id="itr" min="-45" max="45" value="0" /></p>

<svg viewBox="0 0 1400 900" style="outline:1px solid red;">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="hexagonal-mask">
      <circle cx="700" cy="-40" r="705"></circle>
    </clipPath>
    
    
     <g id="cl">
      <!--<rect x="-32" y="-15" width="64" height="224" fill="gold"/>-->
      <circle r="15" fill="#fff"></circle>
      <line y2="180"></line>
      </g>
  </defs>
  
  
  
  <image clip-path="url(#hexagonal-mask)" height="100%" width="100%" xlink:href="https://assets.codepen.io/222579/castell.jpg"></image>
  <circle cx="700" cy="-40" r="655" stroke="#fff" stroke-width="1px" fill="transparent"></circle>
  
  
  <g id="theG" transform="rotate(0 700 -40)">
    
    
<g id="dot2007" transform="rotate(0 700 600)">
<!--transform="rotate(-25 668+32 600+15)"-->
<svg x="668" y="600" width="64" height="224" viewBox="-32 -15 64 224" >
      <use xlink:href="#cl"/>
      <text y="200">2007</text>
    </svg>
    </g>   

    
<g id="dot2006" transform="rotate(0 302 480)"> 
<!--transform="rotate(-25 270+32 465+15)"-->
<svg x="270" y="465" width="64" height="224" viewBox="-32 -15 64 224">
      <use xlink:href="#cl"/>
      <text y="200">2006</text>
    </svg>
</g>
    
<g id="dot2008" transform="rotate(0 1100 480)"> 
<!--transform="rotate(-25 1068+32 465+15)"-->
<svg x="1068" y="465" width="64" height="224" viewBox="-32 -15 64 224">
      <use xlink:href="#cl"/>
      <text y="200">2008</text>
    </svg>
    </g>

  
  </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод ответа [Rotating a SVG circle with group element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63150753/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Comment: Это же дублирование

Comment: @Voprositel Дублирование чего?  Появился на Enso второй авторский ответ и я его добавил к существующей ассоциации вопроса-ответа

Comment: извиняюсь, не заметил